# How to title-case specific characters

Tags: dictionary, python-3.x, formatting, case

So I created my dictionary and then thanks to the help of some nice fellows in this site I managed to have the keys printed to the users in a nice way. Then on my own I figured how to order the dictionary by values so that I could print the only the keys in an ordered fashion.

Here is where I'm at:

```
diff_dict = {'easy':0.2, 'medium':0.1, 'hard':0.05} # difficulty level dict

from collections import OrderedDict

diff_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(diff_dict.items(), key= lambda x: x[1], reverse\
 = True))


print ('\nHere are the 3 possible choices: ', ' - '.join(diff_dict))
```

Which outputs:

> Here are the 3 possible choices:  easy - medium - hard

So my first thought was to make it even nicer by formatting those keys like so:

```
print ('\nHere are the 3 possible choices: ', ' - '.join(diff_dict).upper())
```

> Here are the 3 possible choices:  EASY - MEDIUM - HARD

Better, how about I try capitalizing only the first letter? So I looked into it and my first thought was to find some formatting to specify the first letter. I couldn't find a solution or better said, I found one that left me with some more questions:

```
print ('\nHere are the 3 possible choices: ', ' - '.join(diff_dict).title())
```

> Here are the 3 possible choices:  Easy - Medium - Hard

So that's exactly the output i was looking for, But I'm the curious kind so I wanted some feedback on things such as:

1. What if I wanted to achieve the same but with string formatting such as str.upper?
2. What if I wanted to change specific characters not just the first? (replace, case, whatever)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use an `OrderedDict` for this. Much easier with a list comprehension:

```
options = [o.title() for o in sorted(diff_dict, key=lambda k: diff_dict[k], reverse=True)]
print('\nHere are the 3 possible choices: ', ' - '.join(options))
```

The `[expr for var in iterable]` list comprehension applies the `.title()` method to each string we get from sorting the keys of `diff_dict`. This way, you can format each word separately, instead of applying `.title()` to the already joined whole.

This prints:

> Here are the 3 possible choices:  Easy - Medium - Hard

If you want to see why this works, here are some of the constituent parts:

```
>>> sorted(diff_dict, key=lambda k: diff_dict[k], reverse=True)
['easy', 'medium', 'hard']
>>> [o.title() for o in sorted(diff_dict, key=lambda k: diff_dict[k], reverse=True)]
['Easy', 'Medium', 'Hard']
>>> ' - '.join([o.title() for o in sorted(diff_dict, key=lambda k: diff_dict[k], reverse=True)])
'Easy - Medium - Hard'
```

Hopefully that gives you some ideas on how to manipulate each option string with other methods.

Comment: Thanx for the input, but I'm still having trouble casing specific characters, being those at a specific position, like second character in word, third or last,etc or maybe just searching for "a" and replacing with A, etc. I managed to use in your answer something like o.upper[1]() for o in sorted(... but then when it prints i ONLY the Uppered second characters instead of the while word with the 2nd characters upped-  ['A', 'E', 'A']

Comment: @Newbie: For *arbitrary* uppercasing the only option you have is string splicing (slice string until one char before replaced char, then add one uppercased letter, then add rest of string). What do you need that for?

Comment: thanx for tipping me in the right direction i came up with a solution to "arbitrary" format characters in a string. I'll make a new post with my findings since i hven't been able to see anything like it in SO. cheers